# string builder and string output

Tags: java, string, output

Although the I have converted the output to a `String`, the output on the console is "Solution@3343c8b3". Thanks.

```
public class Solution { 

    public String convertToTitle(int n) {

        if (n < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input a wrong number");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (n > 0) {
            n--;
            char ch = (char) (n % 26 + 'A');
            n = n / 26;
            sb.append(ch);
        }

        sb.reverse();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The test class:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int f = 2;

        Solution f1 = new Solution();
        f1.convertToTitle(f);

        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print the value returned by your method : `convertToTitle` like :

```
String title = f1.convertToTitle(f);
System.out.println(title);
```

Also, *this might not be your concern at this time*, your `System.out.println(f1);` is printing the string which is provided by default implementation of `toString` in `Object` class.

You should override `toString` method in your `Solution`.

Answer (score 4):

You should Override `toString` method in your class.

The output you're getting is the default implementation of [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) which displays the class's name followed by `@` and then the hashcode:

> The `toString` method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character '@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

Also note that `convertToTitle` returns a `String`, you can simply print it.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that `f1.convertToTitle(f);` returns a `String` - OP could just print that.

Comment: no probs! I concur the `toString` override part is a much better solution too.

Answer (score 2):

You print an `Solution` object, not the `String` created by `convertToTitle`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to print the output of `convertToTitle` therefore in your main you need to have

```
System.out.println(f1.convertToTitle(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

you are returning a string object when you are calling f1.convertToTitle(f);, but you are not using it. Instead you are printing f1.

If you want to get the returned output you should use

```
String output=f1.convertToTitle(f);
System.out.println(output);
```

Or, if you want to print something else from the Solutions you should override toString method and the use System.out.println(f1);